# Programmatically setting NSLayoutConstraints for UITableView and UISearchBar

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I've got a `UIViewController` that does add a `UISearchBar` and a `UITableView` in it's `-viewDidLoad` method as subviews of it's `view` property. After adding those, I create constraints using the visual format language like this:

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"searchBar": [_searchController searchBar],
                        @"dataTable": [self tableView]};

NSArray *horizontalSearchBarConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[searchBar]|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:views];
NSArray *horizontalDataTableConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[dataTable]|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:views];
NSArray *verticalSearchBarDataTableConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchBar(44)][dataTable]|"
                                                                                         options:0
                                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                                           views:views];
NSMutableArray *allConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:horizontalDataTableConstraints];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:horizontalSearchBarConstraints];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:verticalSearchBarDataTableConstraints];

[[self view] addConstraints:allConstraints];
```

Read: The widths should be the whole screen's width, the `searchBar`'s height should be exactly 44 and the `dataTable`'s height should stretch out from the bottom of the `searchBar` to the bottom of the view.

Before doing that, I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for those views to `NO`. The `UIViewController` itself gets presented in a modal view. We're talking iOS 6.

What I get: An empty view. Just plain white.

What did I miss? I'm still new to Auto Layout and try to wrap my head around it.

Thanks!

Update: Adding the entire `-viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    BOOL translatesAutoreszingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [[self view] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:translatesAutoreszingMaskIntoConstraints];

    // manually create the search bar
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [searchBar setDelegate:self];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
    [searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:translatesAutoreszingMaskIntoConstraints];

    // create the search bar controller
    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    [_searchController setDelegate:self];
    [[_searchController searchResultsTableView] setDelegate:self];
    [_searchController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
    [_searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];

    // add the search bar
    [[self view] addSubview:[_searchController searchBar]];

    // manually create the table view and add it to the view
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [_tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];
    [_tableView setSeparatorColor:NEA_COLOR_MEDIUM_GREY];
    [_tableView setBackgroundColor:NEA_COLOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND];
    [_tableView setDataSource:self];
    [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    [_tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:translatesAutoreszingMaskIntoConstraints];

    [[self view] addSubview:[self tableView]];

    // set up the layout using Auto Layout
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"searchBar": [_searchController searchBar],
                            @"dataTable": [self tableView]};

    NSArray *horizontalSearchBarConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[searchBar]|"
                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                                        views:views];
    NSArray *horizontalDataTableConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[dataTable]|"
                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                                        views:views];
    NSArray *verticalSearchBarDataTableConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchBar(44)][dataTable]|"
                                                                                             options:0
                                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                                               views:views];

    NSMutableArray *allConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:horizontalDataTableConstraints];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:horizontalSearchBarConstraints];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:verticalSearchBarDataTableConstraints];

    [[self view] addConstraints:allConstraints];

    // add our little gradient
    UIImage *shadow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar_bg_shadow"];
    UIImageView *shadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:shadow];
    [shadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 900, 14)];
    [shadowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [shadowView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:shadowView];

    // add the cancel button for the search bar
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui_navigationbar_close"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:cancelButton];

    // set a short back button title
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

Update: Additional Infos

The encapsulating `UINavigationController` is being created through a storyboard. In there, added a `UIViewController` set to my class as it's `rootViewController`. Thats all.

When I manually add the width in that format string, it displays the views. So when I manually specify the sizes, it works. But then, I guess, I could simply use frames instead…

Comment: Do you add [[self view] addSubview:[_searchController searchBar]];[[self view] addSubview:[self tableView]];? Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, I add them like that and nope, unfortunately I don't have any errors on the console.

Comment: I need more information, can you share your code?

Comment: Very strange, but your code work for me correctly. MB you can share all project? or test?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the project. The client would not be amused. ;-) Instead, I added some more infos. Maybe that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43060/discussion-between-flohei-and-bimawa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your issue was resolved or not, but I noticed a potential problem in your code.

Try eliminating the following line of code:

```
[[self view] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:translatesAutoreszingMaskIntoConstraints];
```

Don't set that property to NO for the root view.